# jquery and user city

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have another question: when user selected dynamic tab its swapped image. How to save user made changes in SQL or maybe in XML file :)

How JapanPro wrote `$.post('sendData.php', function(data) { $('.result').html(data); });` it can be solution. But someone can show example for sendData.php

Maybe:

```
<?php
    $packed = $_GET['data'];
    $data = split(",", $packed);
    for ($i = 0; ($i < count($data)); $i++) {
        ....
```

I don't know, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Keep it simple**

its simple just pass js data to php file, in php file read those data , update sqlquery and return true; receive true in js , update success using DOM

**Watch similar tuts video**

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8HoVdenZFM

Comment: Okey there is my code: https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=19sv2ifYqeWLVhE4vdk3HCc63rwu1MpyD6eCdDXl2Mdk&hl=en

Comment: Image swap is working. but jquery dont swap image through div id but div class. If I can make it swap image through div id it will be easy for jqery .post an php .get. Because ID is unique each dinamic div.

Answer (score 0):

For the packed data the best solution is use any javascript json encoding library (for example, if you use jQuery, http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) and then decode it in the server side `json_decode($data);`

Comment: tnx mate, i will see for your solution :)